# Customize breaks on a color gradient legend using base R

Tags: r, graphics, raster, spatstat

Here is a sample script using random numbers instead of real elevation data.

```
library(gridExtra)
library(spatstat) #im function

elevation <- runif(500, 0, 10)
B <- matrix(elevation, nrow = 20, ncol = 25)
Elevation_Map <- im(B)
custom <- colorRampPalette(c("cyan","green", "yellow", "orange", "red"))
plot(Elevation_Map, col = custom(10), main = NULL)
```

This is the plot and legend that I get:

[image]

This is the legend that I am trying to recreate in R (this one made in Word):

[image]

I know this is possible and its probably a simple solution but I've tried using some examples I found online to no avail.

This plot (with real elevation data) is an art piece that will be hung in a gallery, with the elevation plot on 1 board and the legend on a separate board. I tried to get R to plot just the plot without the legend using

```
plot(Elevation_Map, col = custom(10), main = NULL, legend = NULL)
```

like I have in the past but for some reason it always plots the legend with the plot. As of right now I'm planning on just cropping the .pdf into 2 separate files to achieve this.

Comment: Where does the `im()` function come from? This doesn't look like `ggplot2` at all.

Comment: My apologies MrFlick, the im() function comes from the package "gridExtra". Most of this script is a hand-me-down, so I'm not sure if its easy to recreate without the gridExtra package, I haven't tried.

Comment: I don't see that function in the `gridExtra` package. Are you maybe using `spatstat`? What does `environment(im)` return?

Comment: @MrFlick I think we can skip `im` function, I think they just want `image` (raster) plot with customised legend changed from `2,4,6,8` to `low,high`.

Comment: @MrFlick You are correct, my bad. The im() function is from spatstat.

Comment: The `spatstat` function `plot.im` used here is based on `image.default`. Take a look at the plots produced by `example(plot.im)` and see if there is something useful there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code in the original post is using the `im` class from the `spatstat` package. The `plot` command is dispatched to `plot.im`. Simply look at `help(plot.im)` to figure out how to control the colour ribbon. The relevant argument is `ribargs`. Here is a solution:

```
plot(Elevation_Map, col=custom(10), main="",
     ribargs=list(at=Elevation_Map$yrange, 
                  labels=c("Low Elevation", "High Elevation"),
                  las=1))
```

Answer (score 3):

Here are two ways of doing it using other packages:

```
# example data, set seed to reproduce.
set.seed(1); elevation <- runif(500, 0, 10)
B <- matrix(elevation, nrow = 20, ncol = 25)
#Elevation_Map <- im(B)
custom <- colorRampPalette(c("cyan","green", "yellow", "orange", "red"))
```

**1)** Using *fields* package, *image.plot()*, it is same "base" *graphics::image.default()* plot but with more arguments for customisation (but couldn't remove the ticks from legend):

```
library(fields)
image.plot(B, nlevel = 10, col = custom(10),
           breaks = 1:11,
           lab.breaks = c("Low Elevation", rep("", 9), "High Elevation"),
           legend.mar = 10)
```

[image]

---

**2)** Using *ggplot* package, *geom_raster* function:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape) # convert matrix to long dataframe: melt

B_melt <- reshape2::melt(B)
head(B_melt)

ggplot(B_melt, aes(X1, X2, fill = value)) +
  geom_raster() +
  theme_void() +
  scale_fill_gradientn(name = element_blank(),
                       breaks = c(1, 9),
                       labels = c("Low Elevation", "High Elevation"),
                       colours = custom(10))
```

[image]

Comment: Is it not possible to get the continuous gradient using fields package?  It's broken into bins unlike the ggplot2 version above.